# CoffeeScript for Multiple Function Arguments to Another Function

Tags: javascript, function, coffeescript

How do I use `CoffeeScript` to call a function with multiple functions as arguments? For example, if I wanted to compile to this `JavaScript`,

```
outerFunction(function(innerFunction1) {
        console.log('argument 1');
    },
    function(innerFunction2) {
        console.log('argument 2');
    },
    argument3
);
```

what `CoffeeScript` code would I use? Assume indents of 2 spaces, even though I used 4 to make it look better on `StackOverflow`. To be honest, getting the `JavaScript` indentation right is hard, too. Regardless, I have tried

```
outerFunction (innerFunction1) ->
    console.log 'argument 1'
(innerFunction2) ->
    console.log 'argument 2'
argument3
```

but the resulting `JavaScript` had `innerFunction2` be at the same level as `outerFunction`, rather than as a child. Using commas did not seem to help, either. Having both functions on the same line like this:

```
outerFunction (innerFunction1) ->
        console.log 'argument 1', (innerFunction2) ->
        console.log 'argument2,
    argument3
```

has the opposite problem: `innerFunction2` becomes a child of `innerFunction1`.

So **how do I make multiple functions be arguments of a single function in `CoffeeScript`?**

Comment: I didn't see that question, probably because I didn't think of them as "anonymous functions". Regardless, no offense, but that isn't a very good question and doesn't have many good answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what you want:

```
outerFunction (innerFunction1) ->
  console.log 'argument 1'
, (innerFunction2) ->
  console.log 'argument 2'
, argument3
```

Unfortunately, you can't write it in CoffeeScript without using either commas or parentheses:

```
outerFunction(
  (innerFunction1) ->
    console.log 'argument 1'
  (innerFunction2) ->
    console.log 'argument 2'
  argument3
)
```

Unless you have a first argument which is not an anonymous function

```
outerFunction argument1,
  (innerFunction2) ->
    console.log 'argument 2'
  (innerFunction3) ->
    console.log 'argument 3'
  argument4
```

Comment: Thank you. I do not like comma-first programming, but I suppose I'll have to get used to it if I want to keep writing `CoffeeScript`.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you are mixing spaces with indents, or your indents are off. Because the CoffeeScript you posted becomes fine JavaScript.

```
outerFunction ->
    innerFunction1 ->
        console.log 'argument 1'
    innerFunction2 ->
        console.log 'argument 2'
    argument3
```

Compiles to:

```
outerFunction(function() {
  innerFunction1(function() {
    return console.log('argument 1');
  });
  innerFunction2(function() {
    return console.log('argument 2');
  });
  return argument3;
});
```

---

its also fairly hard to know what you want, because your example:

```
outerFunction(function() {
    innerFunction1() {
        console.log('argument 1');
    },
    innerFunction2() {
        console.log('argument 2');
    },
    argument3
);
```

is not valid JavaScript

15 warnings

- 2 Missing semicolon.
- 4 Expected an identifier and instead saw ','.
- 4 Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression.
- 4 Missing semicolon.
- 5 Missing semicolon.
- 7 Expected an identifier and instead saw ','.
- 7 Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression.
- 7 Missing semicolon.
- 8 Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression.
- 8 Missing semicolon.
- 9 Expected an identifier and instead saw ')'.
- 9 Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression.
- 1 Unmatched '{'.
- 9 Expected ')' and instead saw ''.
- 9 Missing semicolon.

Four undefined variables

- 1 outerFunction
- 2 innerFunction1
- 5 innerFunction2
- 8 argument3

Comment: You are right, the JavaScript I was trying to use was different from that in the question. I corrected it, but I may need to tweak it a little more.

Comment: My JavaScript isn't perfect, either, but your linter has some false positives. My JavaScript probably confused it.